# Finding the generator of a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

Q) Show that $x$ or $2x$ is a generator of the cyclic group $(\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle)^*$ where $f(x)$ is a cubic irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

My attempt: Let $F= \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/<f(x)>$, $[F:\mathbb{Z}_3]  = 3\implies |F|=3^3=27\implies F\simeq GF(27) \implies F^* \simeq (GF(27))^*\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{26}$

If $x\in F ^* \implies |x|$ divides $|F^*|$ by Lagrange's theorem. $\implies |x|\in \{1,2,13,26\}$.

**I can't understand why $|x|\neq 1,2$?** If $|x|=1$, $x$ is not a generator, but why can't $2x$ be a generator? $|x|=1\implies x=1\implies 2x=2$. Is $2x$ not a generator because $\nexists n$ s.t. $2^n = 1 $ (mod 26). I am also not sure if I should take modulo $26$. I did mod $26$ because $F^*\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{26}$.

Similarly, $|x|=2\implies x^2 = 1 \implies (2x)^2 = 4 \neq 1; (2x)^{13} = 2^{13}x = 2x $ (mod 26) $\neq 1; (2x)^{26} = 2^{26} \neq 1$ (mod 26). Am I thinking right? Thanks.

Comment: If $|x|=1$ then $|2x|=2$. This is because $2x=-x$. OTOH, if $|x|=1$ then $x=1$ and $2x=-1$ so those are not zeros of an irreducible cubic. Similarly, if $|x|=2$ then $x^2=1$ implying $(x-1)(x+1)=0$ implying $x=-1$. Not a zero of an irreducible cubic.

Comment: Thanks! I can't understand why the generator of $F^*$ has to be a zero of $f(x)$?

Comment: The coset $x+\langle f(x)\rangle$, sometimes mildly confusingly abbreviated to $x$, is a zero of $f(x)$. A generator need not be a zero of $f(x)$, but it is given in your problem specification that $x$ is a zero. And the task is to prove that in that case either $x$ or $-x$ is a generator.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how $x+\langle f(x)\rangle $ is a zero of $f(x)$? Appreciate your time.

Comment: $$f(x+\langle f(x)\rangle)=f(x)+\langle f(x)\rangle=0+\langle f(x)\rangle=0_F.$$